# Lithium Model find query with <> operator

Tags: lithium

I'm trying to fetch rows excluding the one which already are in an other table :

```
| Content   | ContentSelected
| ––––––––  | ––––––––––––––––––––––––-
| id        | content_id | operation_id
| 1         | 1          | 9999
| 2         | 3          | 1000
| 3

=> 2,3
```

Here how I tried to run this query :

```
Content::find('all', array(
    'joins' => array(new Query(array(
        'source' => 'ContentSelected',
        'constraints' => array('ContentSelected.operation_id' => 9999),
     'conditions' => array(
         'Content.id' => array('<>' => 'ContentSelected.content_id')
));
```

Here the SQL query run by the adapter :

```
SELECT * FROM "Content" AS "Content"
JOIN "ContentSelected" ON "ContentSelected"."operation_id" = 1
WHERE ("Content"."id" <> 0);
```

Is there another way to performed a query excluding results, or to force the adapter to write `ContentSelected.content_id` instead of `0` in the where clause ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Model::connection()->read()` to run a native sql in Li3. Check this out http://www.jblotus.com/2011/10/25/executing-raw-mysql-queries-in-lithium/

```
Content::connection()->read($your_sql);
```

But before using such a solution. Try to implement your model properly using Model Relationships (http://li3.me/docs/manual/models/relationships.md) so that you don't need to use a native query and let the model does the work for you.

Comment: That's what am I doing right now, but it returns a result as array. I have to cast the results to get objects.

Comment: What is the relationship between Content and ContentSelected ( hasOne, hasMany, or belongsTo?) and while you need to join on a <>?

Comment: Content hasMany ContentSelected and ContentSelected belongTo Content

Comment: Did you try:
Content::find('all', array(
    'joins' => array(new Query(array(
        'source' => 'ContentSelected',
        'constraint' => array('Content.id' => 'ContentSelected.content_id',                                               'ContentSelected.content_id' => array('<>' => '9999')))))
));

Comment: Yes, I tried but it returns the same query and results